# How to disable tooltip opening by hover using Bootstrap Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I using tooltip like in exemple [`Toggle Tooltip`](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/tooltip/#programmatically-disabling-tooltip):

```
<template>
  <div class="text-center">
    <div>
      <b-button id="tooltip-button-1" variant="primary">I have a tooltip</b-button>
    </div>

    <div class="mt-3">
      <b-button @click="show = !show">Toggle Tooltip</b-button>
    </div>

    <b-tooltip :show.sync="show" target="tooltip-button-1" placement="top">
      Hello <strong>World!</strong>
    </b-tooltip>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data: {
      show: true
    }
  }
</script>
```

But I don’t need it to open on the hover. 
Can anyone help to figure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [`tooltip`](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/tooltip/#component-options) component there's a prop called `triggers` in which you could specify the event that could trigger the tooltip :

```
    <b-tooltip :show.sync="show" target="tooltip-button-1"  triggers="click" placement="top">
      Hello <strong>World!</strong>
    </b-tooltip>
```